# ZyXel P8702N portforwarding not working

Tags: networking, routing, port-forwarding

I've recently moved to a new location and because of that I now have a new router. I have tried portforwarding before and everything has worked, since I have gotten this new router, I have not been able to portforward. Everything is correctly set up (static ip address has been set up and entered in to the "PortForwarding" menu in this router), but the port is still not open. I am using port 22. I even tried disabling the firewall of the router with no success. Is there anything else I can do?

Comment: Do you have anything listening on port 22 (SSH server?). Does your ISP block port 22? Who is your ISP? Many ISPs don't allow servers on residential connections and block inbound traffic on all ports < 1024

Comment: Do the following,  check if you have any running Firewall blocking your ports(in the router and host) if you have not then call your ISP to check if the ports are closed by them.